# Golang Error is <nil> instead of EOF when Ctrl-D is pressed on Mac

Tags: macos, go

My code is as follows. It is a simple echo program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    mustCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
}

func mustCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    _, err := io.Copy(dst, src)

    fmt.Println(err)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I also checked keyboard mappings for EOF on mac by using `stty all` it gives `^D` as eof

Output of program is as follows

```
a
b
b
c
c
<nil>
```

Comment: What is the question? It works as intended. You closed the input so error is nil and it's printed due to `fmt.Println` call.

Comment: @ferhatelmas err should not be nil as I have typed in the title of the question. It should be printed as EOF. Also if I add code to compare it to io.EOF it should pass the condition. So I don't know how you are stating it is working as expected

Comment: `err should not be nil`, why? Then any pipe shouldn't work. You piped them and closed the source so no error. Let me give you a better example to see what you're trying.

Comment: @MohitShah — your assumption that the error should not be nil is wrong. Read the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy . It explicitly addresses the topic: *A successful Copy returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because Copy is defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error to be reported.*

Comment: @BrunoReis Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs [golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)  and pointed by @BrunoReis `Copy` is behaving as expected as the `err` will be `nil` if `Copy` is terminated due to `EOF`

Answer (score -1):

In the following, we replace `io.Copy` with `io.CopyN` to set expectation higher and close early.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "log"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  mustCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
}

func mustCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
  _, err := io.CopyN(dst, src, 2000) // 2000 is arbitrary, just big enough

  fmt.Println(err)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Example run:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
EOF
2020/05/26 02:26:04 EOF
exit status 1
```

Comment: Upvoting but not the answer to the question